# Issue with setState when trying to pass data from Child to Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a callback function `selectionHandlerList()` to set my state in Parent component (AudiobookList) from Child (AudiobookDetail). When I run the below code, I get this error message: **"TypeError: this.setState is not a function".**

When commenting out `this.setState({ selectedAudiobook: someArg })` in my `selectionHandlerList()` function, I receive the expected value from the Child component (`from console.log(someArg)`, so the callback must be working properly.

This is the code of my Parent component:

```
class AudiobookList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.selectionHandlerList.bind(this);
      }

    state = { 
        audiobooks: [],
        selectedAudiobook: null 
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('http://www.demo.demo/api/get/all')
        .then(response => this.setState({ 
            audiobooks: response.data }))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }

    selectionHandlerList(someArg) {
        this.setState({ selectedAudiobook: someArg });
        console.log(someArg);
        }

    renderAudiobookChoice(audioBookChoice, selectionHandlerList) {
        if (audioBookChoice === 'all') {
                return (
                    this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => 
                        <AudiobookDetail 
                            key={audiobook.id} 
                            audiobook={audiobook} 
                            selectionHandlerList={selectionHandlerList}
                        />)
                );
            }

        if (audioBookChoice === 'prose') {
            return this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => {
                return audiobook.text_type === 1 ?
                    <AudiobookDetail 
                        key={audiobook.id} 
                        audiobook={audiobook} 
                        selectionHandlerList={selectionHandlerList}
                    />
                : 
                    null;
                });
            }

        if (audioBookChoice === 'poetry') {
            return this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => {
                return audiobook.text_type === 2 ?
                    <AudiobookDetail 
                        key={audiobook.id} 
                        audiobook={audiobook}
                        selectionHandlerList={selectionHandlerList}
                    />
                :   
                    null;
                });
            }
        }

    render() {
        console.log('ABL: ' + this.state.selectedAudiobook);
        const selectionHandlerList = this.selectionHandlerList;
        const { audioBookChoice } = this.props;

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.renderAudiobookChoice(
                    audioBookChoice, 
                    selectionHandlerList
                )}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

export default AudiobookList;
```

I am under the impresseion, that the issue must be with `bind`ing `this` properly. But I am not able of figuring it out from related questions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `.bind` on a function returns a new version of that function. You have called `.bind`, but you also have to reassign the function to the "bound" version of itself.

"TypeError: this.setState is not a function" is almost always caused by this simple error. Something like this should correct the issue:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectionHandlerList = this.selectionHandlerList.bind(this);
}
```

This part of the React docs explains more about why this is the case https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#es6-classes

---

Another way of structuring your code which avoids this problem is to use an arrow function class property. For example:

```
selectionHandlerList = () => {
  // this.[everything] works here, because `this` 
  //is preserved from outer scope within an arrow function
};
```

This feature still a proposal, but it does have babel support. You would need to enable `transform-class-properties` or enable `stage-2` in Babel to use this syntax.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much.